# SDL2 and OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: opengl-es, sdl, sdl-2, opengl-es-3.0

I am trying to setup SDL2 (latest master branch) to use OpenGL ES 3.0 on Windows 7 64 bit desktop.

Do I need something like glew for this? as far as I am aware Nvidia drivers allow ES 3.0 contexts natively but I might be wrong?

Do I need an emulator like this: http://malideveloper.arm.com/resources/tools/opengl-es-emulator/?

I downloaded the ES 3.0 headers from Khronos site but really not sure what to link with.